# in octobercms using laradock nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon & doesnot work.but manually run works.how to resolve?

Tags: queue, jobs, octobercms

we use
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database')
while running php artisan queue:work --timeout 3600 it work
but when running nohup php artisan queue:work --tries=3 --daemon & it works for the current job queued sinlge row for one time only.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the queue in laravel is not enough, you need to setup a cron job entry for octobercms.

See the installation guide for [Setting up the scheduler](https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation#crontab-setup)

Comment: m confused if  queue related to scheduler setting.i just want to run queue:work run automatically in my production. It works fine doing manual.do i required to setup scheduler for running php artisan queue:work automatically.i have laravel project and nohp php artisan queue:work --daemon & works absoultely fine.but seems issues in octobercms

Comment: You need to tell the operating system to call the laravel scheduler on a regular basis. This is done by the cron job entry. Laravel cannot start the jobs automatically, it  is called by the operating system.

Comment: nope its not working dude.just ran and test by adding schedule in crontab -e  and added nohup php artisan queue:work it didnt help

Comment: nohup in cron jobs is not necessary. Also take care on the limited environment under which cron jobs were executed. Write a shell script wrapper that creates output/logfiles to debug further.

Comment: Simply the question is how to use php artisan queue:work  in  octobercms in production to make queue job run continiously if any rows in jobs table available without  scheduler.